# Does the Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser control implement a same origin policy?

Tags: ajax, windows-phone-7, browser, same-origin-policy

I have some HTML files I'm putting in Isolated Storage and then loading them up in a Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser control. I want to make an AJAX request in JavaScript to a remote host to get some data. This appears to fail with a "No transport" error. I assume there is a same origin policy which is preventing my request from going through.

Does anyone know if this is the case, and if so, can the policy be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462081(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462081%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> Content loaded from Isolated Storage or dynamically by using the NavigateToString(String) method is treated differently than content loaded from the network. Content loaded from Isolated Storage or dynamically by using NavigateToString has no cross-site restrictions, while content loaded from the network has normal cross-site restrictions. For this reason, you should be careful about loading untrusted content from Isolated Storage or dynamically by using NavigateToString.

So, answer to your question would be: Yes it does, but not for files loaded in the way you describe.